# verification of precipitation forecast

Tags: verification, forecasting

I was wondering if someone could help me do some verification analysis using the R verification package. I have 2 sets of precipitation data, one is observation on a 20x20x100 (latitude x longitude x day) matrix, and the other is the model results on a 20x20x100x5, where the last dimension is the ensemble member. In other words, the model was run 5 times for the same 100-day period.

My goal is to plot reliability diagram based on this data.  The data is in inches/day.

My main questions are:
1) how to get the forecast probabilities based on this dataset? In other words, how to go from inches/day to a binary or categorical forecast?

2) I guess that first I need to choose some reference values (terciles?), which I'll use to get my binary/categorical results.  But I don't have a clue on how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.
Alex K.

Comment: What do you mean from 'categorical forecast'? As i understand, you have observed data, and the model-forecast data. What about calculate the difference err = prec(obs) - prec(forec)?

Answer (score 1):

You can change to binary [0,1] by first defining a threshold value e.g. average precipitation (x1) and find out whether the forecast values exceed [1] or do not exceed [0] the threshold value. Once you have your forecast categories (0,1), you can now test this against the observed values to see which agree or not agree...For example you can go

forecast  <- ifelse(observed$value==x1,0, 1 & ifelse(observed$value>x1,1,0)) 
observed  <- ifelse(observed$value<=x1,0,1)

next you can assess the agreement between your forecast and obsevation using the verify function in the verification package
Ver<-verify(forecast, observed, frcst.type = "binary", obs.type = "binary")
summary(Ver)

this is not exhaustive and I hope it helps. Richard: University of Sydney